# What are the advantages of using GitLab CI/CD to build and deploy vs doing everything from my own machine?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

CI/CD From Google  search:

GitLab CI (Continuous Integration) service is a part of GitLab that build and test the software whenever developer pushes code to application. GitLab CD (Continuous Deployment) is a software service that places the changes of every code in the production which results in every day deployment of production.

As a Visual Studio user, what have I been missing all these years? I build from C# and then deploy through FTP. Why even use GitLab for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to take a look in the features page https://about.gitlab.com/stages-devops-lifecycle/continuous-integration/

Gitlab has too much features that will be difficult to summarize them here